# Assign a list of sums to indexed variables

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to generate a list of sums `{a, b, c, d, ..., z}`

and assign them to a list of variables such that

```
b[1] = a

b[2] = b 

b[3] = c

...

b[26] = z
```

Answer (score 5):

Presuming your list of sums is a list of numbers -- for example something like what the following generates

```
SeedRandom[42]; sums = RandomReal[100., 26]
```

then

```
Evaluate[Array[b, 26]] = sums;
```

will do it. You can check that the assignments have all been made as requested by evaluating

```
Table[b[i], {i, 26}] == sums
```

> True

You can also view them directly

```
DownValues[b]
```

[image: table]

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear[b];

Evaluate[Array[b, 26]] = CharacterRange["a", "z"];
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Array[(b[#] = FromCharacterCode[# + 96]) &, 26]
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless there are other needs, I'll consider using a single "variable" `bl` and assign your whole list to it

```
bl = {a, b, ... }
```

You can of course access every single element of the list with `Part` (i.e. double braket)

```
bl[[1]]
```

> ```
> a
> ```

Often using a single "variable" offer more opportunities in subsequent computations.